# How do i create the dots used for slides,with only html and css?

Tags: html, css

how do i create the dots used in navigation,slides.Using only Html and CSS.

Like this one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qocTe.jpg

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those are carousel indicators. Search for carousels and you’ll find them automatically. As for now this question is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Just provide your code so far. You did try it on your own, did you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, let's define the HTML markup. 
Generally a simple list:

```
<ul class="nav-dots-container">
    <li class="nav-dot"></li>
    <li class="nav-dot"></li>
    <li class="nav-dot"></li>
</ul>
```

After this, add some style:

```
.nav-dots-container .nav-dot{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   background: #666;
   border-radius: 100%;
   margin: 3px;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

At least, a bit of extra-styling:

```
.nav-dots-container .nav-dot.active{
  background: teal;
}
.nav-dots-container .nav-dot:hover{
  background: blue;
}
```

This is just a basic example.

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/gtk7jm14/

Comment: That's exactly what i wanted,thanks!